# <ui-view> doesn't show me the default template

Tags: angularjs, maven, angular-ui-router

I'm new to AngularJS.

I'm using maven and Spring MVC + AngularJS. Before AngularJS I used to use Spring form so I'm migrating now from Spring forms to AngularJS.

The problem I'm facing is that I'm triying to use ui-router following an example but in my case, the template I created doesn't show at all as a default template.

So I have my module here

```
angular.module('electronicaDonPepe', ['ui.router'])

    .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

        $stateProvider
            .state('login',{
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: 'http://localhost:8585/electronicaDonPepe/resources/templates/login.html',
                controller: 'LoginController'
            });
    }]);
```

Then my controller:

```
angular.module('electronicaDonPepe', [])
    .controller('LoginController', ['$scope', '$http', '$state', '$stateParams', 
        function($scope, $http, $state, $stateParams) {
            $state.go('login');

            $scope.save = function(){
                var param = {
                        dni: $scope.usuario.dni, 
                        contrasenia: $scope.usuario.contrasenia
                };

                $http.post("http://localhost:8585/electronicaDonPepe/login/check", param).then(function(){
                    $state.go('login');
                });
            };
    }]);
```

Then, I have my simple HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

<!-- Jquery -->
<script src="http://localhost:8585/electronicaDonPepe/resources/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

<!-- AngularJS -->
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://localhost:8585/electronicaDonPepe/resources/js/angular.min.js"></script>


<!-- Complementos JS para Bootstrap -->
<script
    src="http://localhost:8585/electronicaDonPepe/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="http://localhost:8585/electronicaDonPepe/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Mis CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="http://localhost:8585/electronicaDonPepe/resources/css/edp.css">

<!-- Complementos para AngularJS -->
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://localhost:8585/electronicaDonPepe/resources/js/angular-ui-router.js">

</script>

<title>Electronica Don Pepe</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="electronicaDonPepe">
    <div class="container text-center">
        <h1>ELECTRONICA</h1>
        <br>
        <h2>DON PEPE</h2>
        <br>
        <hr>
        <br>

    </div>

    <ui-view></ui-view>

    <div class="container text-center">
        <a href='http://localhost:8585/electronicaDonPepe/about.html'>Acerca
            de</a>
    </div>

</body>

<!-- Mis archivos AngularJS -->
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://localhost:8585/electronicaDonPepe/resources/js/app.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://localhost:8585/electronicaDonPepe/resources/js/LoginController.js"></script>

</html>
```

I'm having no errors at all. I downloaded AngularJS batarang and I can't debug anything.

I almost forgot, here is the template:

```
<div class="container">

    <form class="form-signin">
        <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Usuario</label>
        <input ng-model="usuario.dni" type="text" id="inputText" class="form-control" placeholder="Usuario" required="required" autofocus="autofocus"> 


        <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Contraseña</label> 
        <input ng-model="usuario.contrasenia" type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Contraseña" required="required">

        <div class="checkbox">
            <label> <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me">
                 Recordar usuario  
            </label>
        </div>
        <button ng-click="login()" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Iniciar Sesión</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

I think there is something in the code I'm missing. Any idea/ help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
angular.module('electronicaDonPepe', [])
```

This redefines the module that you already defined before. So your module doesn't depen on ui-router anymore, and doesn't contain any state definition anymore after this line is executed.

To get a reference to an already defined module, the syntax is

```
angular.module('electronicaDonPepe')
```

Note: I also find it very strange that the first thing you're doing in your controller, which is the controller of the login state, is to tell the router to go to the login state. If the controller is instantiated, then you're *already* in the login state.

Also, hard-coding `http://localhost:8585` everywhere will make it very hard to access the application from anywhere other than your own machine.

Comment: You were right as always. I don't have to explain myself but I want to, so  in the part I tell the router to go to login I was just trying to force it to work. I didn't realize to delete that part before show my code. About the hard-coded http, well ... this is a project for a university subject called advanced programmation II. My teacher asked me to avoid the use of scriptlets if I choose to use AngularJS. Before that I could use <%= request.getContextPath() %> but now I don't see another option. Is there something you can recommend me?